# Find cell form control element sits on top of in Excel

Tags: excel, range, form-control

In VBA macro how do we find the range of the cell that a particular form control element sits on top of in Excel? I'm using an imperfect/inaccurate way to do so:

```
Dim cBox As Shape
Dim LRow As Integer
Dim LRange As String
Set cBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("cbTorF") 'checkbox/element name'
LRow = cBox.TopLeftCell.Row
LRange = "B" & CStr(LRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be more "accurate" to use one cell down and to the right:

```
Set rng = cBox.TopLeftCell.Offset(1,1)
```

Assuming the form is large enough to cover that cell.